# Handle and suggest version number in Mercurial using tags, How to handle Branches

Tags: mercurial, branch, versioning

I'm developing an extension for Mercurial that can handle version numbers using Mercurial tags. Currently, it checks if the version number specified is in the right order with the others version numbers in the repository and if it is not too far from the previous one.

However, for now it only work if the repository has only one branch. I'm trying to make it operational on repo with branches and more, on repo with divergent development line (kind of unnamed branch). One of the tricky part is to define what the user can do and what it cannot. For examples, if on branch A there is the version 1.1 and 1.0.1 on branch B I think the Branch B should always stay below 1.1. As I'm not familiar with lots of different way to manage version numbering in branch development, I want to gather use cases and how to handle it.

So, I want to know if someone have already done research on the subject or knows good sources to help me solve this problem. You can also submit use case to handle.

Obviously, I did some research but I cannot find anything really relevant. Probably because I don't know how to express the problem in a concise and search engine comprehensive way.

Edit: Here is what "rules" I figured out for now :

- On each branch, the version number should be higher than the previous one (but not too higher)
- When you create a branch you can put any version number you want higher than the previous one.
- When the first version number is defined on each branch, that define the order for the entire branch. A branch can never overtake another one.
- Those rules are inherited by all further branches.
- When you merge two branches (actually it is the annoying part), the common mercurial attitude is to consider the result of the merge as a part of the local branch. In my case it seems not to be the right behavior. It's would be very strange if when you merge the 1.0.3 branch with the 1.1.0 version from 1.0.3 that you only can use version below 1.1.0 because this branch is below the other one. The solution I suggest here is always treat the merge as the part of the highest branch otherwise some branch will regress.

Can you tell me if this is consistent or if I miss some important use cases.

**The first part of the question is still on topic. If you know any relevant information on the subject or if you know a similar problem please tell me.(after all, its only rules of numbering in a tree)**